# Custom edit action on UITableViewCell crashes on swipe by trying to delete

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I added a custom swipe to share action on my UITableViewCells in my UITableView. My problem is that for some reason it won't even let me swipe the cell. It immediately crashes with this line:

> reason: 'attempt to delete row 25 from section 0 which only contains 25 rows before the update'

However, I'm not trying to delete anything! It's a share button not a delete button. Here are the relevant methods I've added:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Share") { (action: UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Void in
        // Some stuff
    }
    shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    return [shareAction]
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}
```

Why is my table view controller giving me this error when it should have no business attempting to delete anything?

Comment: You have to delete data source of the table view also.

Comment: Removing the data source for my table view did not fix this.

Comment: Can you please post the code where did you remove it?

Comment: You have to delete that data from the array first then only update the table

Comment: I'm not trying to delete anything. That's what I'm trying to say. I am not trying to swipe to delete any row. I am trying to swipe to show a custom action that is not destructive.

Comment: That didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was an issue unrelated to the three methods above. My table view controller is a PFQueryTableViewController subclass which has `numberOfRowsInSection` baked in out of the box. My problem was that I explicitly added that method when I shouldn't have. Therefore it was being called when it shouldn't have been (it's build into the subclass implicitly), resulting in some wonky behavior. I removed my call to `numberOfRowsInSection` and it worked as it should.